# What is the difference to using '\n' and '\12' in C

Tags: c, ascii

The line feed (LF) has an ASCII code number 10. Is `'\n'` implemented as something MORE than a simple non-printable ASCII character?

Are there any C language specific details?

Comment: @AlterMann: It's not a "printing character" in the way the C standard uses that term. For example, `isprint('\n')` is false.

Comment: @KeithThompson, oops, you are right!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The character constant `'\n'` represents what the C standard calls the "newline" character.

The standard doesn't say what the value of that character is. It happens to be 10 (`LF`) on systems that use an ASCII-based character set (that includes Unicode) -- but the C standard doesn't require ASCII. (Starting with the 1999 standard, implementations *may* indicate that they support Unicode by predefining `__STDC_ISO_10646__`, but that's optional.)

IBM mainframe systems, for example, use a different and incompatible character set called [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebcdic). On such systems, `'\n'` will have a value other than 10.

<strike>Incidentally, `'\10'` has the value 8, not 10. That syntax uses octal (base 8), not decimal. Character 10 is represented as `'\12'` (or as `'\xa'` in hexadecimal).</strike> (The question was updated to correct this.)

Comment: So on a Linux system, the newline character should "unfold" into a simple LF non-printable character?

Comment: Note that there are platforms which even though they are ASCII-based use something other than 10 (LF) for `'\n'` (e.g. "classic" Mac OS used 13 (CR)).

Comment: @Rasteril: On a Linux system, the character constant `'\n'` is essentially equivalent to the integer constant `10` (or `012`, or `0xa`). When printed to an output stream in text mode, it's converted to the system's representation for an end-of-line marker -- which, on Linux happens to be the character with the same value. (On Windows, printing `'\n`' has the effect of writing two characters, `CR` and `LF`.)

Comment: @PaulR: I know classic Mac OS used `CR` to mark end-of-line in text files -- but did C compilers actually use the value 13 for the constant `'\n'`, or was it converted on input and output? I suspect the latter, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Keith: yes, IIRC most/all compilers converted both `\r` and `\n` to CR (13), as LF (10) was not really supported by the OS. One more data point: Windows generates CR + LF for `\n` (unless the file is opened in binary mode).

Comment: @PaulR: That's not quite what I meant to ask. In a C program compiled and executed on classic Mac OS, would the expression `'\n' == 13` be true, or would `'\n' == 10` be true? The value of the constant `'\n'` and the character printed by `putchar('\n')` are separate questions. (And I don't think the C standard would allow `'\n' == '\r'`)

Comment: @Keith: good question - I don't know the answer I'm afraid and I don't have a classic Mac OS system any more to try it on. The only thing I can say for certain is that writing `'\n'` to a file generated an ASCII CR.

Comment: FWIW, on modern systems with `__STDC_ISO_10646__` defined and `__STDC_MB_MIGHT_NEQ_WC__` not defined, `'\12'` and `'\n'` are required to have the same value, the value of the UCS/Unicode character `U+000A`.

Comment: @PaulR: I've posted that question about classic Mac OS [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25065940/827263).